# Calculate number of days in a range constrained to some data given that it can overlap

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table named 'contracts' with columns: `id`, `date_from`, `date_to`, `id_user`.

I want to calculate, given a range of dates, how many days during that range did a user have a contract, regardless of how many contracts she had (that is, counting the days just once even if there are overlapping contracts).

For example, given this data:

```
id      date_from     date_to        id_user
1       2016-10-26    2018-12-13     5
2       2017-11-10    2018-12-13     5
3       2018-06-01    2019-12-13     5
4       2018-10-01    2018-11-13     6
5       2017-01-01    2018-03-13     10
6       2019-03-12    2020-01-01     10
```

And given the range

```
SET @from = '2018-03-12';
SET @to = '2019-03-12';
```

I want a query that outputs:

```
id_user    days_in_range
5          365
6          43
10         2
```

Comment: So days are only counted once, regardless of how many overlapping contracts there may have been?

Comment: @Strawberry that's it

Comment: what are your date_from and date_to type data?

Comment: @WisangJatiAnggoro TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,date_from DATE NOT NULL
,date_to DATE NULL
,id_user INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2016-10-26','2018-12-13',5),
(2,'2017-11-10','2018-12-13',5),
(3,'2018-06-01','2019-12-13',5),
(4,'2018-10-01','2018-11-13',6),
(5,'2017-01-01','2018-03-13',10),
(6,'2019-03-12','2020-01-01',10);

SELECT id_user 
     , MIN(date_from) date_from
     , date_to 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.id_user
            , LEAST(x.date_from,COALESCE(y.date_from,x.date_from)) date_from
            , MAX(GREATEST(x.date_to,COALESCE(y.date_to,x.date_to))) date_to 
         FROM my_table x 
         LEFT 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id_user = x.id_user 
          AND y.date_from <= x.date_to 
          AND y.date_to >= x.date_from 
          AND y.id > x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY id_user,date_from
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY id_user,date_to;
+---------+------------+------------+
| id_user | date_from  | date_to    |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       5 | 2016-10-26 | 2019-12-13 |
|       6 | 2018-10-01 | 2018-11-13 |
|      10 | 2017-01-01 | 2018-03-13 |
|      10 | 2019-03-12 | 2020-01-01 |
+---------+------------+------------+

SELECT id_user
     , SUM(DATEDIFF(LEAST('2019-03-12',date_to),GREATEST('2018-03-12',date_from))) delta 
  FROM
     ( SELECT id_user 
            , MIN(date_from) date_from
            , date_to 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT x.id_user
                   , LEAST(x.date_from,COALESCE(y.date_from,x.date_from)) date_from
                   , MAX(GREATEST(x.date_to,COALESCE(y.date_to,x.date_to))) date_to 
                FROM my_table x 
                LEFT 
                JOIN my_table y 
                  ON y.id_user = x.id_user 
                 AND y.date_from <= x.date_to 
                 AND y.date_to >= x.date_from 
                 AND y.id > x.id 
               GROUP 
                  BY id_user,date_from
            ) a 
        GROUP 
           BY id_user
            , date_to
     ) m
 WHERE '2018-03-12' <= date_to
   AND '2019-03-12' >= date_from
 GROUP
    BY id_user;

+---------+-------+
| id_user | delta |
+---------+-------+
|       5 |   365 |
|       6 |    43 |
|      10 |     1 |
+---------+-------+
```

(I think I haven't properly accounted for where Event A overlaps Event B overlaps Event C, but hey, this is the data set I was given)